# how compare rows together?

Tags: r, data.table, bioconductor

I have  data like as below:
I want to compare each row with rows below and then get number of equal value in each 2 rows.

```
   V1  V2  V3   V4  V5
1   3   2   2   3   3
2   2   2   0   2   3
3   2   3   2   2   0
```

I wrote the code below, but in out put I face with NA.

```
library(data.table)
data=as.data.frame(read.table("data.csv",header=TRUE))

findMatch <- function(i,n){
  tmp <- colSums(t(data[-(1:i),]) == unlist(data[i,]))
  tmp <- tmp[tmp > n]
  if(length(tmp) > 0)return(data.table(sample=rownames(data[i],duplicate=names(tmp),match=tmp))
  return(NULL)
}
tab <- rbindlist(lapply(1:(nrow(data)-1),findMatch,n=0))
tab
```

out put:

```
       sample duplicate match
 1:      1        NA    NA
 2:      1        NA    NA
 3:      2        NA    NA
```

I expect this out put:

```
       sample duplicate match
 1:      1        2    2
 2:      1        3    1
 3:      2        3    2
```

- I want to compare all rows together, here I just showed row 1 with other rows. I like do it for all rows.

Comment: Can you post the expected output ?

Comment: `as.data.frame` is irrelevant in `data=as.data.frame(read.table("data.csv",header=TRUE))`

Comment: i'm also confused why you're using `read.table` considering you're already loading `data.table`... see `?fread`.

Comment: I used as.character but did not get out put.

Comment: The sample data you provide has 2 equal values between each 'successive' rows, but your sample output shows something else in the 'match' column. Can you clarify what exactly qualifies as a match?

Comment: Column "match" show equal value between two compared rows. eg. between row 1 and row 2 there are 2 same values.

Comment: In your sample data if you compare Row 2 to Row 3 there are also 2 equal values (V1 and V4), but your sample output for row 2 shows "match" as `1`. Why 1, not 2?

Comment: Or are you comparing the first row to all other rows, not ever comparing row 2 to row 3?

Comment: I want to compare all rows together, here I just showed row 1 with other rows. I like do it for all rows.

Comment: Please make your sample output *complete* for your sample input. Make the sample input smaller if that helps.

Comment: Except from a typo in `..sample = rownames(data[i, ]), duplicate = ..`, your code seems to work fine